# Should I rescind a referral to a Recruiter in the light of subsequent behaviour?

Tags: references, referral

I am in a dilemma and hope I can get some advice from you.

I worked with a recruiter and got an Offer. On the basis of this, several of my peers asked to be referred to that recruiter. I obliged and send an email to the recruiter with 4 referrals.

A girl of 4 people, is a very close friend with him. He told me that she has already taken an offer based on a small town but refused an offer based on NY where my company is, because her bf works in that town and she won't go to NY even though she will get the offer from my company. I just talked to the girl and she said she decided to go to NY and turn down the offer in the small town,which is what she always said to the guy.
I was so surprised cuz he and she is very close! I'm closed to him too, but he just lied to me to squeeze out his friend! I have no idea what he'll do to me if there is any interest conflicts in the future.

I am not going to withdraw the other referrals, My question is: Should I inform the recruiter about this persons actions?

Comment: What were you trying to achieve by making the referrals and were these just referrals or more like recommendations?

Answer (score 6):

The friend, who asks you to withdraw one of the other 3 referrals, is being too unreasonable and unprofessional. He has no right to ask you to withdraw one of the 3 referrals because the other 3 people have the right to seek jobs just as that friend does.

Tell that friend to be cool and be reasonable. That friend can apply for many other jobs on his own if he wants to increase his "**competitiveness**" on the job markets.

You should not withdraw any referrals that you already sent the recruiter.

You don't need to tell the recruiter anything at all. The recruiter and the hiring manager can look at all 4 resumes and decide who to interview.

Answer (score 3):

Me, Personally (because I'm really disagreeable), if someone asked me to do that, I'd rescind their referral to the recruiter and leave everyone else as is.

Not from vindictiveness, but because if they have pulled that kind of stunt with me, they will likely pull it with someone else and that I feel that would reflect badly on me and my reputation.

That said, the best course of action is probably to do nothing. You've made the referral, it's now up to the Recruiter to see if they have positions for which the individuals you've put forward are suitable.

Comment: I am not sure whether you'd rescind his referral or do nothing?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how this was presented to the recruiter: was it a referral "here is someone who might be interested, but I don't know them very well" or a recommendation "This person is awesome. Take a look, you won't regret it".

I have no problems doing both but I'm typically VERY clear about which of the two it is and I only give true recommendations if I know the person well, have a high opinion of them, and some data to back it up.

If these were just referrals, than there is no need to follow up. It's up the recruiter to figure out what they need to figure out. If it was an actual recommendation, I would probably follow up to protect your own reputation and credibility. Needless to say to: you should remove the obnoxious candidate from your recommendation list.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand the American workplace culture.I said: He is good at doing xx and very interested in join our company.  I'd appreciate it if you(my recruiter) provide him with an interview. Is that a referral or recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

Ask the guy a simple question. "Do you think you are the best person for the job, of the people I've referred?"

If he says "Yes" then respond "So what are you worried about? You'll be the one getting the job."

If he says "No" then respond "Then it would be unfair to my company if I didn't refer the best person for the job to them".